# Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am making an interactive timeline in Dreamweaver using HTML, CSS, and javascript. I have the background of my timeline and want to place it in a div. The problem is, the timeline is really long and I only want to display some of it and I want the user to be able to scroll horizontally back and forth.  Any direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply this CSS to your DIV:

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: I would upvote you if I had the reputation......

Comment: Did it actually work for you? I'm trying to simulate the situation but can't get it to work. If it indeed fixed it, you could always mark as "accepted answer", no need for reputation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x:scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

You should not create horizontal scroll in your webpage. It is bad code and is really inconvenient for the user. I would suggest making the page vertical put including anchors